# open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly AppLinks.dll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to consume a Rest API to display a listView with MVVM so I created this this service to consume the Rest API:

```cs
 public class MachineService : IMachineService
    {
        public  string Base_url = "https://169.254.178.79:45455/api/";

        public async Task<ObservableCollection<Machine>> GetMachines()
         {
             string url = Base_url + "machines";

             HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
             HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);

             if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
             {
                 var result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Machine>>(result);
                 return json;
             }
             return null;
         }
```

And this is the ViewModel:

```cs
public class MachineListeVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        IMachineService _rest = DependencyService.Get<IMachineService>();
 


        public MachineListeVM ()
        {
           GetMachines();
        }

        public async void GetMachines()
        {
            var result = await _rest.GetMachines();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    Machines = result;
                }
                    
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Machine> machines;
        public ObservableCollection<Machine> Machines
        {
            get { return machines; }
            set
            {
                machines = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Machines"));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

the exception details while debugging:

```
>[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppLinks.dll
[SurfaceFactory] [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@e0b84b8
[ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]] hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
[libMEOW] applied 1 plugins for [com.companyname.app5]:
[libMEOW]   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
[InputTransport] Create ARC handle: 0x7a825386a0
[libMEOW_gift] etEventThreadFunc()::thread Begin. eventRefCnt: 1
[PhoneWindow] DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@8503464, this = DecorView@374f6cd[MainActivity]
[ViewRootImpl[Syncfusion License]] hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
[InputTransport] Create ARC handle: 0x7a825ecf60
Thread started:  #5
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

**Note: I tried the same code in another project and it's worked fine and the list view is apeared**

Comment: what line causes the NullReferenceException?

Comment: when the program arrived in the view model constroctor he normally go to the GetMachines method in MachineService But he doesn't do that and it returned to the oncreate in the MainActivity to cause the exception

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about calling async methods from a constructor.  It is generally not a good idea.  You should at least initialize `machines` when you declare it - that would probably help avoid this problem.  All the other log messages you posted are probably not related to the actual problem you are having.